# I need hint for of the given set is Countable / uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X_j=\{0,1\}$ for every $j=1,2,\dots$. Let $$Y=\prod_{j=1}^{n} X_j $$
which of the following is/are true:

1. $Y$ is countable.
2. Card Y = card [0,1]
3. $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\prod_{j=1}^{n} X_j) $ is uncountable
4. Y is uncountable.

This question ask in exam I want to solve. And where I get more such example for practice. Thank You.

Comment: X_i all have cardinality 2.  So what is cardinality of X_1 x X_2?  Of X_1 x X_2 x X_3?

Comment: Hint: in trying to second guess how text tend to write these questions... I find the actual answers rather ... unusual.  Not wrong or incorrect; just unusual for the typical such questions.  I have to wonder if you transcribed them correctly.

Comment: Most likely $Y=\prod_{j=1}^\infty X_j$.

Answer (score 0):

$Y$ is in fact a finite set with cardinality $2 \times 2 \times \cdots \times 2$ ($n$ times). This can be seen by the following result.

Let $A $ be a set with $n$ elements and $ B $ be a set with $m$ elements. Then $A \times B$ has $nm$ elements.

Indeed, counting of elements of $A \times B$ amounts to selecting one element from $A$ and one from $B$. Since the number of choosing an element from $A$ is $n$ and the number of choosing an element from $B$ is $m$, one concludes that above claim.

Thus $Y$ is a finite set with $2^n$ elements, and hence is countable.

2. is false. Cardinality of $Y$ is not that of $[0,1]$, However if the variable of your product is running from $1$ to $\infty$, then it is true.
3. is false. In fact, it is countably infinite. Its cardinaltiy is that of $\mathbb N$, the set of all natural numbers.

It follows now that $4$ is false too.